# Simple customized button in android

Tags: android, xml, android-button

I've used the tutorial in this [link](http://www.dibbus.com/2011/02/gradient-buttons-for-android/) which demonstrates a great way of using different colors for buttons.

He has demonstrated all the colors for the buttons as below

[image]

**Ex::** for red He mentions as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#ef4444" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#992f2f" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#ef4444"
                android:endColor="#992f2f"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#992f2f" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

But he has not mentioned the color for Orange in the

- Can someone give a demonstration with Orange color
- **Specifications** must be same as the ones mentioned for other colors
  but color must be orange

Comment: All you need to do is change the hex colors for each of the shapes. You should be able to determine the basic pattern he sets up in his blog post and swap out the hex colors (e.g. #ef4444) for an orange (e.g. #ff8800). However, there are a nearly infinite number of shades of orange and combinations that can form a gradient, so it's up to you to pick the exact colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check all color codes [here](http://www.computerhope.com/htmcolor.htm)

just replace your desired color in

```
 <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#ef4444"
                android:endColor="#992f2f"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#992f2f" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
```

These two lines

```
  android:startColor="#ef4444"
   android:endColor="#992f2f"
```

padding is the inside spacing and stroke is the width of boundary of button. just replace the colors in gradient tag and make your desired button.

Answer (score 0):

### I just wanted to post the code for answer ( thanks to Brontok & Tanis .7x)

**I found the solution**::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#ff8800" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#992f2f" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#ff8800"
                android:endColor="#992f2f"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#992f2f" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```